# CountDownTimer nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, countdowntimer

In my Android application i encounter **sometimes (rarely)** the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at     development.nk.quizfootball.MyDialogFragment$MyCountDownTimer.onTick(MyDialogFragment.java:679)
at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:124)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment

Inside MyDialogFragment i create my custom CountDownTimer:

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }   

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        progressBarI++;
        mProgressBar.setProgress(progressBarI);
        Log.d("MyCountDownTimer","onTick, progressBarI= "+progressBarI);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        progressBarI++;
        mProgressBar.setProgress(progressBarI);

        updateParentActivityUI();
        if(soundEffectsHere) {
            if (mp_error!=null) {
                mp_error.start();
            }   
        }

        if(getActivity()!=null) {
            ((GameplayMain)getActivity()).dismissDialog();
            if(endGame) {
                endGame();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Line 679 is the following:

```
mProgressBar.setProgress(progressBarI);
```

Please can you tell me where the problem might be?

mProgressBar is initilized at onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, container, false);

    int counter=0;
    btn = new Button[Eight_buttons.length];
    for(int j : Eight_buttons) {
        btn[counter]=(Button)v.findViewById(j);
        ((Button) v.findViewById(j)).setOnClickListener(this); //-->sets click listener
        counter++;
    }

    checkHelps(); //-->Ελέγχω αν έχω ήδη χρησιμοποιήσει κάποια/ες βοήθειες

    Log.d("MyDialogFragment > onCreateView", "mmQuestion= "+mmQuestion);
    btn[0].setText(Protection.decode(mmQuestion, StartupActivity.myName));

    divideAnswersToButtons(); //--> Moirazw tyxaia tis 4 apantiseis sta 4 buttons

    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));

    mProgressBar=(ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    mProgressBar.setProgress(progressBarI);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `mProgressBar`?

Comment: post that code and check if the layout inflated in fragment has a progressbar

Comment: Also, check that you are starting the timer *after* you initialize mProgressBar.

Comment: Make sure you have initialize your mProgressBar before start MyCountDownTimer.

Comment: the problem i describe does not happen always. Only some times.

Comment: myCountDownTimer is initilized and started at onCreate

Comment: @N.K. does `fragment_question.xml` have a progress bar?

Comment: yes of course     fragment_question.xml does have a progress bar. The problem is not happened every time i run this app but only sometimes.